# What is the best way to implement REST with Spring security?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, restful-authentication

I've implemented a web application with form and OpenID authentication, but in addition I want make my webapp RESTful. On the other hand requests to REST should be accesible only to authenticated users.

What is the best way to make my REST service secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [example](https://github.com/pshirishreddy/secure-rest) . I guess that solves your problem. A little google search yielded me to that [page](https://github.com/pshirishreddy/secure-rest).

Comment: Thanx a lot. I'll consider this solution.